# Having multiple decorators in Django and using only one

Tags: django, decorator, django-authentication

I am using [django-tokenapi](https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi) to allow for authentication of an Android project that is using Django as a backend.  The project also has a web interface.

django-tokenapi uses the `@token_required` decorator to protect certain views.  Django uses the `@login_required` decorator to protect certain views.

What I would like is to have only one view that is protected by `@login_required` OR `@token_required` so it can be used with either the webapp or Android app.

So, ideally, it would look like this:

```
@token_required
@login_required
def names_update(request):
    ....
    ....
```

However that does not work.  Is there a better method of doing this?  Or is the correct thing to have two views, one the webapp and one for Android, that are protected by the proper decorator, and then lead to the same method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try assigning a new view variable to the old view:

```
@token_required
def names_update_token(request):
    ...

@login_required
names_update_login = names_update_token
```

This should have the effect of creating a second view named names_update_login which is just a pointer to the first so that the code remains the same.

EDIT:

Another thought, and one I have used, is to create a more "generic" view and call it from each of the other views:

```
def update_token(request):
    ...

@token_required
def names_update_token(request):
    update_token(request)

@login_required
def names_update_login(request):
    update_token(request)
```

This gets around the issue you mentioned while still maintaining only a single copy of the actual code that implements the view.

Comment: Interesting idea.  When I try it, it is throwing a syntax error.  I think the decorator is expecting a function after it.  Is there something else that might work?

Comment: When faced with a similar situation I have simply called one function from the other.

Comment: yeah this will work.  But it requires two urls.py settings to be maintained for each function.  One for the webapp and one for the Android app.

Comment: Yes, not ideal but serviceable.

Answer (score 1):

No there's no easy way, if possible at all, to write an generalized `OR` decorator according to you described.

However, you can write a new decorator that does exactly what you want:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def token_or_login_required(view_func):
    """
    Decorator which ensures the user is either logged in or
    has provided a correct user and token pair.
    """

    @csrf_exempt
    @wraps(view_func)
    def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.REQUEST.get('user')
        if user and user.is_authenticated:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

        token = request.REQUEST.get('token')

        if user and token:
            user = authenticate(pk=user, token=token)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return _wrapped_view
```

this decorate combines both [`token_required`](https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi/blob/master/tokenapi/decorators.py#L10) and [`login_required`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L44) decorators, and will allow access to the view either if the user is logged in, or the token is valid.

Comment: is there a way to do this using a reference to the decorator code as opposed to the actual code?

Comment: @AlexisK I am not sure what you mean by reference, but you can put this code anywhere then just import it and use it as any other decorators.

Comment: I mean that it is copying and pasting code that is from another place.  Is there a way to avoid the copying and pasting of the code?  That way if things are changed in those libraries later, things will still be ok

Comment: @AlexisK ah I see what you meant. Unfortunately you can't do that with these decorators.. Think of this case: when neither token or logged in, which `else` would you like to run? One decorator would redirect and the other would return `HttpResponseForbidden()`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use more than one decorator on a single view. But in this case I think you should seperate the view and apply the decorators seperately. Otherwise `token_required` decorator will try to authenticate using token which won't be available on a request made using browser.